# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'. > Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, realm-mobile-platform, epson

I'm trying to integrate my application with EPSON thermal printer TM-T82.
My application use realm for local database.
I tried as per their documentation to integrate printer and i'm getting this error.
I used EPOS2.jar file and libepos2.so file

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.**

> Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
>     Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration. For more information, go to:
>      https://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/add-native-code.html
>     Alternatively, you can use the experimental plugin:
>      https://developer.android.com/r/tools/experimental-plugin.html

**app:build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.swishpay.tab"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
compile 'com.pusher:pusher-java-client:1.5.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/Sam4sAndroidSDK.jar')
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
compile(name: 'MswipeWseriesUniversalDRDSDKVer1.0.6v3.3.0', ext: 'aar')
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
implementation files('libs/simplyprintapi-android-1.3.0.jar')
compile 'com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:1.2.1'
implementation files('libs/ePOS2.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**project : build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to 
all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.2.0"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Prefer CMake to the experimental plugin, Realm does not support the experimental plugin.

Comment: some how it worked by adding .so file in all jniLibs folder ( armeabi, armeabi-v5a, armeabi-v7a, mips, x86) and adding         ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v5a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
        } 
in default configuration

Answer (score 0):

You have to add c++ support in order to use c++ files in your project. Please make sure that your project have this support. You can go through this link [Add C and C++ Code to Your Project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)  hope it will be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ndk {
           abiFilters "armeabi-v5a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
        }
```

add this in gradle default config and create these folders in jniLibs and paste the *.so file in all folders. This will enable the support for multiple ndk's